# Grails index of each

Tags: groovy

I've the following codes in my controller. How do I access the each index?

```
def arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']

arr.each
{
// 'it' is the element
println it
}
```

Comment: There's some basic documentation that would help you out with all sorts of questions about collections and maps in groovy - have a look at http://groovy.codehaus.org/For+those+new+to+both+Java+and+Groovy It's an excellent summary, and doesn't waste time referring everything back to Java.
http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections
http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1025-Arrays
http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [eachWithIndex](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#eachWithIndex(groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
arr.eachWithIndex { obj, i ->
    println "${i}: ${obj}"
}
```